# Postgress psycopg2 python select - relation "modelo" does not exist

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

An AWS Aurora Postgress is with some tables, it was just created and i'm testing the psycopg2 connection.

The code bellow returns the tables created.

```py
# Create a cursor
cur = conecta() //cod com login, host, bd name,..
# Query to list all tables
query = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'schema';"
# Execute the query
cur.execute(query)
# Get the result
result = cur.fetchall()
# Iterate over the result and print the table names
for table in result:
    print(table[0])
# Close the cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

But when i make a select,

```py
# Create a cursor
cur = conecta()
# Execute the SELECT statement
cur.execute("SELECT \* FROM Table_Name")
# Fetch the rows
rows = cur.fetchall()
# Print the rows
for row in rows:
    print(row)
# Close the cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

```
UndefinedTable

Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_196871/3150531950.py in \<module\>
6
7 # Execute the SELECT statement
\----\> 8 cur.execute("SELECT \* FROM Table_Name")
9
10 # Fetch the rows

UndefinedTable: relation "Table_Name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT \* FROM Table_Name
```

I try to select from information_schema.tables and a see the table in the result
I try to check the default schema.
Passing the schema in the sql select.
check table permissions.
say a prayer.

Comment: 1) Why are you escaping the `*` e.g. `\*`? 2) What is the table name in the database?

Comment: You probably need to append name of your schema to your table name, since it looks like it's not the default one. Something like select * FROM schema.Table_Name